# Language based RewriteRule like mysite.com/en/ in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond, language

I'm trying to write redirect directives in the .htaccess to forward internally all user requests like this:

- Every request in a language folder should redirect to the requested file with the language query string:

```
example.com/en/contact.php -> example.com/contact.php?lang=en
```

- Redirect any request without language path to a default language folder like this:

```
example.com -> example.com/en
```

- Remove trailing slash if the address is entered with it:

```
example.com/en/ to example.com/en
```

- For the folder projects, every request should lead to the view-project.php file with the respective query strings:

```
example.com/en/projects/test -> example.com/view-project.php?lang=en&path=test
```

Here is my attempt, but it's not working without trailing slash on a request like: http://www.example.com/de and is not redirecting http://www.example.com to a default language folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/\.]+)/?$ view-project.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I achieve this?

This is possible a duplicate and I apologize for that. I searched everywhere and read about 100 posts, but I didn't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: So example.com/de/ works, but not example.com/de? Just to make it absolutely clear.

Comment: @vidarlo exactly

Comment: To clarify, the language "folder" is not a physical directory? "Every request in a language folder" - is this literally every request (as per your directive), or just `.php` files that exist at the following URL-path? What about static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.)? Are these also in a language "folder"? Or should they be excluded? "Redirect any request without language path" - literally "any request"? No exceptions? What about static resources?

Comment: "Add a trailing slash" - only after the "language folder" (as per your example), or should this be more general (although from your other examples I don't think this can be any more general). Should requests for `/en/` be rewritten to `index.php`? In your example you are rewriting this to literally `?lang=XX` (which is not strictly a valid end-point), this requires mod_dir issuing a subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex` (which is not explicitly set here, so is not guaranteed to work with the code as posted).